# Rails:Automatic Validation of Attribute Accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I am new to Rails and I encountered a unique behaviour(seems magick to me for now).

I added an attribute accessor in a models file

```
attr_accessor :git_url
```

I am sure I did not add any **validation** for this **accessor**.

I am using **simple form** gem for forms. When I include this accessor in the form and submit the form by entering invalid url, a hint appears (**Please enter a URL**) and form does not submit

```
<%= f.input :git_url %>
```

Its cool but I wanna know from where is this validation coming

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to readme, **git_url** ends with **url**. This is triggering **input type=url**](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're seeing is simple form's HTML5 client side validations.

For Example,

If you setup the input as a `:url` field. This would setup some client side validations automatically.

```
<%= f.input :git_url, as: :url %>
```

You could verify that this is the case by disabling the client side validations entirely.

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, html: { novalidate: true }) do |form| %>
```

Comment: I am not using as: :url